# Using SQL Server back end for Subversioning Repositories

Tags: sql-server, svn

Has anyone attempted to use SQL Server Database as a Subversion file system back end? 
So that all Subversion Repositories would be stored in a SQL Database instead of a flat file system? Make for easier backups and reporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not feasible. The entire  core of subversion would need to be rewritten. Subversion does support a Berkeley db implementation, and with the proper tools, this db could be exported to mssql for reporting.

Comment: Not the entire core, just the svn "filesystem" layer.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion has two different repository formats. There's the default FSFS which uses a 'flat' file system.
But you can also create repositories which use the berkeley db.

To create such a BDB repository, use the command

```
svnadmin create path/to/repository --fs-type BDB
```