# subversion with sqlserver as backend

Tags: sql-server, svn, fsfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using MSSQL backend for Subversioning Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398802/using-mssql-backend-for-subversioning-repositories)

can we use sqlserver as backend in subversion(instaed of fsfs)?

Comment: A duplicate thread available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398802/using-mssql-backend-for-subversioning-repositories

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, Subversion only offers two types of repository storage — FSFS (Fast Secure File System) and Berkeley DB. FSFS works faster on directories with a large number of files and takes less disk space, due to less logging.[3] Subversion has some limitations with Berkeley DB usage leading to repository corruption and data loss when a program that accesses the database crashes or was terminated forcibly.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software))

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT Possible.